# Why I am not able to print space character?

Tags: c

This is my code:

```
int main(void)
{

    int i, j, k, n;
    char userLatter, space;
    printf("please enter an uppercase letter:\n");
    scanf("%c", &userLatter);
    n = 9;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        space = ' ';
        for (j = 5; j > i; j--)
        {
            ++space;
        }


        for (k = 0; k <= i ; k += 1)
        {
            printf("%c%c%c", space, userLatter, space);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Can you please tell me what I should do so I can print the space character?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `++space;` for? Remove it, and the space will be printed correctly.

Comment: What is `++space` supposed to do? You're incrementing a char, meaning that `space + 1` is ' ! ', `space+2` is ' " '... is this the desired behavior?

Comment: im trying to increment the space so it will have 4 spaces in the first loop, the 3 in the second and so on..I realized something is wrong there, appreciate if you can help. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You keep turning the space into something else with the line:

```
++space;
```

What did you expect that to do?  Are you trying to make it a string of multiple spaces

You can left-pad your character by using a `printf` format specifier.  Try this:

```
int width = 4;
char letter = 'A';
printf( ":%*c:\n", width, letter );
```

That would output 3 spaces and the letter A:

```
:   A:
```

And if you simply want to put a space in, don't forget you can just put a space in the format string.  As in the famous:

```
printf( "Hello, world!\n" );
```

Note there is a space in there.

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick respond. I'm trying to add another space character @paddy

Comment: what actually i need to print is a pyramid created by the user input. and i need to create it using a for nested loop, so i though creating the number of spaces i need in the first loop, thank 1 less in the next, and so on..is that the right direction ? @paddy

Comment: Instead of doing `++space`, you could just do `printf(" ")` or `putc(' ')`.  Or you could use the width-specifier trick I showed you and don't do spacing in a loop.  Either way, I don't see why you need to print trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't Java. There are no `Strings` in `C`. Alternatively, you use `char[]`. You can't say `++space` and expect `space` to concatenating it's self. `++space` is the same as saying `space = space + 1` in `C`. Doing this will add 1 to it's ASCII value, if I'm not correct. `space` is a char and can only hold ONE char at a time. If you want it to hold more than one character, than you have to make it an array. Here is an alternative:

```
char space[5]; //This would be done at the top when you initialize it
/* Many lines of code later */
for(j = 5; j > i; j--){
    space[j] = ' ';
}
```

FYI that `n` is doing completely nothing and is wasting space. Sorry my OCD senses were tingling.

Comment: thanks allot buddy. your explanation helped! @Rob Avery IV